# CSV database input causing a line for each column

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have successfully got the data coming from a csv into the database but for some reason the query produces the same results 7 times the same number of column in the csv.

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$user="general";
$pass="gretna22607";
$db="general";
$con=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql' . mysqli__error());
mysqli_select_db($con,$db) or die ('Error connecting to database' . mysqli__error());
$empty="TRUNCATE csvimport";
mysqli_query($con,$empty);

$csvdata = file_get_contents('http://www.overclockers.co.uk/productfeed/b2b_cs312.csv');

$csv_file="ocuk.csv";

if (($getfile = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
                $num = count($data);
                for ($a=0; $a < $num; $a++)
                    {
                        $results=$data;
                        $str = implode(",", $results);
                        $slice = explode(",", $str);
                        $col1 = $slice[0];
                        $col2 = $slice[1];
                        $col3 = $slice[2];
                                            $col4 = $slice[3];
                                            $col5 = $slice[4];
                                            $col6 = $slice[5];
                                            $col7 = $slice[6];

                        // SQL Query to insert data into DataBase

                        //$query = "INSERT INTO csvimport (tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, tmp4, tmp5, tmp6, tmp7) VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."','".$col6."','".$col7."')".";";
                        //$query = "INSERT INTO csvimport VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."','".$col6."','".$col7."','','','')".";";
                        //mysqli_query($con,$query);
                    }
                $query = "INSERT INTO csvimport (tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, tmp4, tmp5, tmp6, tmp7) VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."','".$col6."','".$col7."')".";";
                                 mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }
    }
fclose($csv_file);
mysqli_close();

?>
```

for example

if i echo query

the first one would be like this

```
insert into csvimport ('test','test','test','','','','');
insert into csvimport ('test2','test2','test2','','','','');
insert into csvimport ('test3','test3','test3','','','','');
insert into csvimport ('test4','test4','test4','','','','');
insert into csvimport ('test','test','test','','','','');
insert into csvimport ('test','test','test','','','','');
insert into csvimport ('test2','test2','test2','','','','');
insert into csvimport ('test2','test2','test2','','','','');
```

i want it to just take each line of the csv once and input it into the database with all 7 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this line:

```
$data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",");
```

Then move these lines:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO csvimport (tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, tmp4, tmp5, tmp6, tmp7) VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."','".$co$
//$query = "INSERT INTO csvimport VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."','".$col6."','".$col7."','','','')".";";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

outside the `for loop`

Comment: Once it finished running ill post update, problem one fixed but it has introduced a new problem :(

Comment: nope it is still doing it but instead of one after the other it now running other statements before rerunning them, in fact it seems to have went into infinity loop

Comment: Can you update the question with the changed lines? I am not sure what changes you have made

Comment: updated code, updated example basic it wil do line 1, then lien 2 then lien 3 then lien 4 then line 2 then lien 5 then line6 then line 1 then lien 1 etc no clear pattern

Comment: watching phpmyadmin and refreshing teh rows keep goign from 20000 to 23000 so it deleting rows and inserting new ones indefintiely

Comment: I think there is something else running here then. Because in the code you provided there is no delete command at all

Comment: updated with all teh code expect commented out stuff apart from what is in the for loop

Comment: @AndrewCrawford I ran your code through a csv file I have and it works exactly as intended without any errors. Are you saying you do not want duplication if all the fields are same?

Comment: If that is what you want, is there any unique field in the row to identify it?

Comment: all i want it to do is read row one insert, read row two insert, read row three insert etc, butjust now it seems to be readreading the rows after doign them, it might be cache eithe ron teh server oor my browser ill do some tests and and then edit if necessary

Comment: @AndrewCrawford there is either some serious miscommunication or some something of that kind, When I run your code on my csv - I can read row one, insert it - read row two, insert it - and so on...